# how to encrypt a JSON payload using RSA with XML public key and then encode it into hex in node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, hex, rsa, public-key-encryption

encrypt a JSON payload using RSA with public xml key and encode it into hex in node.js

tried with node-rsa

Comment: can you give more information @geethika

Comment: Could you show how you tried and the problem you are experiencing with node-rsa ?